# Get value from all sliders when a button is pressed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

In order to make the sliders I am pulling them from another class that I have created using a name, low value, high value, and step size for the slider, but the issue is that I cannot pull the value from the sliders. I get an attribute error, so I am curious if there is a work around to this. Perhaps, storing the final slider position after it stops moving or something similar to that? Any help would be appreciated. Below is the code and the class that I am pulling from.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from slider import SliderDisplay


class SpringMassDamper(QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    QMainWindow.__init__(self)
    self.setWindowTitle('Spring Mass Damper Simulation')

    # Main Widget
    widget = QWidget()
    self.setCentralWidget(widget)

    # Layout
    layout = QVBoxLayout()
    widget.setLayout(layout)

    # Quit button
    quit_button = QPushButton('Quit')
    quit_button.clicked.connect(app.exit)

    # Simulate System Button
    simulate_button = QPushButton('Simulate System')
    simulate_button.clicked.connect(self.print_values)

    # Labels
    self.title_1 = QLabel('System Parameters')
    self.title_1.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
    self.title_2 = QLabel('Simulation Parameters')
    self.title_2.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)

    # Slider
    self.mass_slider = SliderDisplay('Mass:', 0, 10, step=1000)
    self.spring_slider = SliderDisplay('Spring:', 0, 10, step=1000)
    self.damper_slider = SliderDisplay('Damper:', 0, 10, step=1000)
    self.time_slider = SliderDisplay('Time(s):', 0, 100, step=1000)
    self.timestep_slider = SliderDisplay('Time Step(s)', 0, 10, step=1000)

    # Layout
    layout.addWidget(self.title_1)
    layout.addWidget(self.mass_slider)
    layout.addWidget(self.spring_slider)
    layout.addWidget(self.damper_slider)
    layout.addWidget(self.title_2)
    layout.addWidget(self.time_slider)
    layout.addWidget(self.timestep_slider)
    layout.addWidget(simulate_button)
    layout.addWidget(quit_button)


def print_values(self):
    x = self.mass_slider.value()
    print(x)
    #print('Mass:', float(self.mass_slider.value()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    interface = SpringMassDamper()
    interface.show()
    app.exec_()



class SliderDisplay(QMainWindow):
def __init__(self, name, low, high, step=1000):
    QMainWindow.__init__(self)
    self.setWindowTitle('Slider Display')

    # Main Widget
    widget = QWidget()
    self.setCentralWidget(widget)

    # Layout
    layout = QHBoxLayout()
    widget.setLayout(layout)

    # Labels
    self.name = QLabel(str(name))
    self.label = QLabel(str(low))

    # Slider
    self.slider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, self)
    self.slider.setMinimum(low)
    self.slider.setMaximum(high*step)
    self.slider.setValue(low)
    self.slider.valueChanged.connect(self.change_value)

    # Layout
    layout.addWidget(self.name)
    layout.addWidget(self.label)
    layout.addWidget(self.slider)

# Function for changing value of label to the slider and accounting for step
def change_value(self):
    num = (float(self.slider.value())) / 1000
    self.label.setText(str(num))
```

Comment: share your slider.py, please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Change `x = self.mass_slider.value()` to `x = self.mass_slider.slider.value()`

Comment: Thank you! that was a very easy fix. I really appreciate it